# Can't create Bootnode

Tags: bootnodes

i am trying to set up a local PoA network following this tutorial:

https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8

I am using Windows 10. The issue is that i dont get back an enode address using the following commands:

```
bootnode -genkey boot.key

bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr :30310
INFO [11-20|18:06:05.376] New local node record   seq=1 id=14a0c68dfe9d6ca2 ip=<nil> udp=0 tcp=0
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

to get the enode address use the -writeaddress command

```
bootnode -nodekeyhex 435601bfc51df236b310517ef2233c046cbede662ed5a3c0de5a37c785350d7f -writeaddress
```

Insert your own bootkey (that was generated) and you should see the enode address display. [image]